# change UIButton title after it was hidden

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

**What I want to do is :**

when a user clicks on "forgot password" label:
1- UIButton title changes to "send"

2- password textfield is hidden

3 - cancel Label is NOT hidden

and when a user clicks on cancel : 
1- password textfield is displayed

2- UIButton title is "Login"

3- dance is hidden

```
@IBAction func forgotTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if passwordtxt.isHidden == false {
        loginbtn.titleLabel?.text = "send"

    passwordtxt.isHidden = true
        forgotLab.isHidden = true
        top.constant = -50

        cancelLb.isHidden = false
    } else {
         if passwordtxt.isHidden == true  {
        forgotLab.isHidden = false

        if passwordtxt.isHidden == true {

            passwordtxt.isHidden = false
               loginbtn.titleLabel?.text = "login"
            cancelLb.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    }

}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    cancelLb.isHidden = true
    forgotLab.isHidden = false
    loginbtn.titleLabel?.text = "send"

    if passwordtxt.isHidden == true {

        passwordtxt.isHidden = false

        top.constant = 50


}
}
```

**The issue :**

for now everything works great but when I click on the button when it's "send" it changes to "login"!! it goes back to it's default title in black color

is there anyway to make the UIButton stay "send" even after clicking on it?

*UPDATE*

```
  if passwordtxt.isHidden == false {
        loginbtn.setTitle("send", for: .normal)

    passwordtxt.isHidden = true
        forgotLab.isHidden = true
        top.constant = -50

        cancelLb.isHidden = false
    } else {
         if passwordtxt.isHidden == true  {
        forgotLab.isHidden = false

        if passwordtxt.isHidden == true {

            passwordtxt.isHidden = false
            loginbtn.setTitle("login", for: .normal)
            cancelLb.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    }

}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    cancelLb.isHidden = true
    forgotLab.isHidden = false
    loginbtn.setTitle("send", for: .normal)

    if passwordtxt.isHidden == true {

        passwordtxt.isHidden = false

        top.constant = 50
}
}
```

Comment: There is, but first, what *exactly* do you want to see when the "send" UIButton is tapped? (The "brute force" way to do this is to have the logic in `forgotTapped(sender:)` check what is in the label and process accordingly. But there may be a more elegant way.)

Comment: When changing the title use the function `setTitle` instead of changing it from the titleLabel.

Comment: I want to to be "send"

Comment: what do you mean ? @TawaNicolas

Comment: instead of using `loginbtn.titleLabel?.text = "send"` do `loginbtn.setTitle("send", for: .normal)`

Comment: The `titleLabel` should only be accessed to change the appearance of the label. Changing the title messes things up because the titles are stored somewhere else in the `UIButton` object. So, if you change the title via `titleLabel` and then tap on the button, you're changing the state of the button, which makes the button object reset the title depending on the values entered using `setTitle`.

Comment: please check my updated question. This doesn't change "login" at all, it stays login all the time

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func forgotTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if passwordtxt.isHidden == false {

    passwordtxt.isHidden = true
        loginbtn.setTitle("send", for: .normal)

        forgotLab.isHidden = true
        top.constant = -50

        cancelLb.isHidden = false
    } else {
         if passwordtxt.isHidden == true  {

        forgotLab.isHidden = false

        if passwordtxt.isHidden == true {

            passwordtxt.isHidden = false
            cancelLb.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    }

}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    loginbtn.setTitle("login", for: .normal)

    cancelLb.isHidden = true
    forgotLab.isHidden = false

    if passwordtxt.isHidden == true {

        passwordtxt.isHidden = false

        top.constant = 50


}
}
```